# PHP Variable into MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, get

I'm having a small problem with my PHP code... I've searched on the forum and copied the code but I must be doing something wrong. I'm trying to order the results I'm getting on a page I have by name, year etc. using a variable. But it isn't working?

I've got this:

```
$orderby = 'name';    //'$_GET['orderby']' <---- I'd like to use this later to make it dynamic
$req = mysql_query('select id, name, year, genre, cover from table ORDER BY  `table`.`'$orderby'` ASC');
```

And why isn't the code working? It doesn't give me an error, the page just doesn't load and stays blank!

Comment: What, no rants about using `$_GET` in queries and SQL injection yet? :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the concatenation :

```
$req = mysql_query('select id, name, year, genre, cover from table ORDER BY  `table`.`'.$orderby.'` ASC');
```

Or

```
$req = mysql_query("select id, name, year, genre, cover from table ORDER BY  `table`.`$orderby` ASC");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `'$orderby'` to `'.$orderby.'`. `.` is php concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$req = mysql_query('select id, name, year, genre, cover from table ORDER BY  `table`.`' . $orderby . '` ASC');
```

or

```
$req = mysql_query('select id, name, year, genre, cover from table ORDER BY  `table`.`$orderby` ASC');
```